# Adwords API queries per second rate limit

Tags: api, google-api, google-ads-api

Does anyone know what the rate limit is for [Adwords API keyword Targeting Ideas service](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/targeting-idea-service)?

It seems they mention some [rate limits](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/rate-limits) but it doesn't seem to have any details around queries per second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not been able to get an official answer on this but support have told me that the rate limit on the targeting ideas service varies by how busy this service is. My experience confirms this.

Also: the recommended backoff of 30 seconds returned in the rate limit error message is almost never enough. I've ended up defaulting to a 2 min backoff for this service.

Comment: is this at account level or global across all accounts?

Comment: It appears to be global - at developer token level - rather than account level.

Comment: I'm now thinking of putting rate limits on my application and maybe limit request to like maximum 2 per second. Do you think this is sufficient to avoid rate limit from their Adwords API?